# python syntax for formatting integer

Tags: python, format

I am new in python. In the following line
    '{0:6}{1:02d}'.format(date, hour)

I figured out that hour should be 0 filled to two digits. But I can't figure out what it is formatting date to be. afaik, both date and hour are int values here.

Comment: an example would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it and see:

```python
a = 10
b = 6
print('{0:6}{1:02}'.format(a, b))
#output => '    1006'
```

So like 02 adds "0"s to the variable until it is of 2 length. Just adding a number (6) will add spaces to the front until the variable length is 6.

[Python's Common String Operator's Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) has more.

Answer (score 3):

`{0:6}` is just going to take the 0th argument (`date`) and print it with a minimum of 6 characters.  It can be an integer, a string, ...  Nothing else special there.  It is a guess at what format was intended for `date` (ie. May1st, 5/1, ...)

You are correct about the interpretation of the `{1:02d}` which is the `hour` field print in a minimum of 2 decimal digits with 0's to pad.